# AdLoader class package not found

Tags: android, package, google-play-services

As per the reference of **Native Ad on Admob** shown below.

https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/rtb/native_ads_for_apps
https://support.google.com/adxseller/answer/6066199
https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/6073023
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/native
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/formats/package-summary

I have browse to above mentioned sites. But not able to find the **jar** which have AdLoader class.
This shows the AdLoader class is used for native ads.

But I am unable to find the AdLoader class in google play services library. Kindly help me out that from where I can get the package which have apis for **native ad** of admob.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should include the ads dependency in your gradle file

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'`

For further details see here: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

Comment: I am using the eclipse IDE for this. Is there anything in eclipse by which I can achieve this task

Comment: I am not aware how far the eclipse gradle support has come. Afaik it should be able to support the scenario already. Otherwise you could copy the jar from the m2repository of your android sdk.

Comment: Yes Mate!!. But if I want to use the AdView class of google play service inside gms package. then I just import the google play services into the eclipse as a library project. And after that I can do further operations by adding that library project into my app. 
but here I am not able to see the AdLoader class. My concern is only to find the AdLoader class into jar. How can I achieve this.

Comment: I have updated the google play services and not able to find the AdLoader class. Is there any other api for handling DFP. If yes then where can I find that apis.

Comment: The best way of action would be to use the gradle build. It simplifies the whole process to a one liner. Also switching to the official AndroidStudio IDE will make your process much simpler.